# Random "Uncaught TypeError" problems after Meteor 0.9.x upgrade

Tags: jquery, meteor, famo.us

I intermittently get these errors on load:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'xyz' of undefined

Clearing the browser cache and reloading sometimes clears up the problem, so it is most likely async/load order related. The basic code works, but sometimes it can't see things that are clearly visible as globals on the window object.

Have ripped out packages and rebuilt app several times. I used to use Famono to get Famo.us, but have had to rip that out and hard-code in all the dependencies as globals (e.g., jonperl:famous-compiled) to get back to work.

These are the packages I have loaded.  I have removed them and reinstalled each of them several times in various orders without luck.

standard-app-packages     1.0.1  Moved to meteor-platform

accounts-password         1.0.1  Password support for accounts

accounts-ui-unstyled      1.0.1  Unstyled version of login widgets

oauth-encryption          1.0.0  Encrypt account secrets stored in the database

coffeescript              1.0.2  Javascript dialect with fewer braces and sem...

cryptoquick:jade          0.2.6  Jade template language for Meteor

cryptoquick:stylus-multi  0.0.6  Stylus, packaged with Nib, Jeet, Rupture, an...

jonperl:famous-compiled   0.2.0  Famous compiled as globals.

iron:router               0.9.3  Routing specifically designed for Meteor

The error is a jquery message.  As I add and delete them I see that jquery version 1.0.0 gets loaded.

So here is the question: Is this bug something that I can fix, or is it fundamental to 0.9.x and I just have to wait until it is resolved by some patch?

Comment: Does it give you a line number? If the error is in your source, just adding a [guard](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/guards) may fix the problem. If the error is in a package then we'll need more information to solve it.

Comment: Thanks Dave.  The line numbers vary, so I don't think it is my code, but adding more guards would almost certainly help. I'm new to JavaScript and its, er, "features."  Haven't had to worry about load order in a long, long time so my defensive coding skills are rusty.

Comment: The common factor seems to be the CoffeeScript class template. Specifically, trying to extend a global object fails intermittently even when the code to load the global object has already run and it should be on window.   I'm follow Meteor's loading style - using deeply nested directories, putting early code into /lib, etc. - and every file logs to console when it loads so I can see the load order.  I log window too, and can see the global object, but that doesn't mean that it was there when the object was fetched to run the class constructor.